# Magento 2 Image in Rss Feed

Tags: magento2, file, rss-feed

I want to customise RSS Feed xml. I am using magento 2.2. I want to show image in rss feed. I am not able to trace the file where I can update my code to show the image in RSS xml. Please help me to find out the file where I can update my code to show the image in RSS xml.

Comment: explain in more details your question

Comment: I have a RSS feed url on my webiste. In this RSS XML only link , description are available but I want also image in this output xml file.

Comment: So I need to identify where I can change the layout of this output RSS xml file.

Comment: @RakeshDonga Sir please help me to find template file.